# .htaccess url encoded string not passing to page correctly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, urlencode

I have a rewrite rule in .htaccess

`RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ my-php-page.php?cid=$1`

I am passing a encoded string which contains characters like `=` and `+` - this is the encoded string;

`V1ihnKpip6WpnY7Wm5zn2+6YUtLf2KCh4eKY`

When in the complete URL it's

`http://www.example.com/my-php-page.php?cid=V1ihnKpip6WpnY7Wm5zn2+6YUtLf2KCh4eKY`

now this doesn't work because of the `+` sign. So I want to send the `cid` urlencoded which then becomes;

`http://www.example.com/my-php-page.php?cid=V1ihnKpip6WpnY7Wm5zn2%2B6YUtLf2KCh4eKY`

The `+` sign becomes `%2B`. This works great, except when I try this through the RewriteRule in .htaccess - it doesn't work. So the URL would be

`http://www.example.com/page/V1ihnKpip6WpnY7Wm5zn2%2B6YUtLf2KCh4eKY`

The mypage.php file actually receives the `cid` as `V1ihnKpip6WpnY7Wm5zn2 6YUtLf2KCh4eKY` for some reason replacing `%2B` with a blank space.

Any ideas why it may be doing that? And how can I fix it. Many thanks for the help.

**EDIT**

I just found this solution - [PHP $_GET var with urlencode and "&" bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626347/php-get-var-with-urlencode-and-bug) - but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution in `.htaccess` than having to `urlencode` the string twice?

Comment: your rewrite rule starts with `page` but your URL starts with `some-page/`

Comment: No it doesn't, the first 2 URL examples link directly to the PHP file, it doesn't use the rewrite. I've rewritten the question as my examples URL's were a bit confusing.

Answer (score 10):

Try adding the `B` rewrite flag. This flag tells mod_rewrite to escape backreferences, the [documentation says this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b):

> _rewrite has to unescape URLs before mapping them, so backreferences will be unescaped at the time they are applied. Using the B flag, non-alphanumeric characters in backreferences will be escaped.

Since the `%` character is reserved for backreferences to groupings matched in `RewriteCond` statements preceeding the `RewriteRule`, mod_rewrite treats them differently and could end up attempting to replace the `%2` with a blank backreference.

So your rule should look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ my-php-page.php?cid=$1 [B]
```

Comment: PHP interprets the + as a space, because historically the + was used for spaces in urls before RFC 3986.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, to redirect this URL:

`http://www.example.com/page/V1ihnKpip6WpnY7Wm5zn2+6YUtLf2KCh4eKY` to this one

`http://www.example.com/my-php-page.php?cid=V1ihnKpip6WpnY7Wm5zn2+6YUtLf2KCh4eKY`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)  http://www.example.com/my-php-page.php?cid=$1 [L]
```

The result is:

`http://www.example.com/my-php-page.php?cid=V1ihnKpip6WpnY7Wm5zn2+6YUtLf2KCh4eKY`

with no change in the parameter.