# .htaccess can't read url with %20

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is how my htaccess file look right now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([\sa-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ view.php?folder=$1
RewriteRule ^([\sa-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ view.php?folder=$1
RewriteRule ^([\sa-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$ view.php?page=$1
```

It accepts the url as:

```
http://localhost/new.html to view.php?page=new
http://localhost/something to view.php?folder=something
http://localhost/something/ to view.php?folder=something
```

but it is not working for url as:

```
http://localhost/something%20else
http://localhost/something%20else/
```

it should be `view.php?folder=something%20else`

Comment: I am not getting any error, its showing blank page with the %20 in the URL.

Comment: No its not working.. `http://localhost/something%20else/` is trying to find the directory in that name, that isn't passed to view.php itself

Comment: its the same, it writes, no such directory as `something else`

Comment: yes, i mean that sir.

Comment: `Not Found

The requested URL /blank hiuz/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.Not Found

The requested URL /blank hiuz/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Comment: there is no error, htaccess isn't even recognizing the pattern

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123490/discussion-between-prakash-and-anubhava).

Comment: Its the 404 error sir. Please write me the htaccess that can process words with space between them as single variable.  My code is not working

Answer (score 1):

[According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13722058/3536236) you should be using a url rewrite flag on your htaccess rewrite.

(shameless quote of link to follow:)

> Try adding the `B` rewrite flag. This flag tells mod_rewrite to escape
>   backreferences, the [documentation says
>   this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b):
>
> > _rewrite has to unescape URLs before mapping them, so backreferences will be unescaped at the time they are applied. Using the B flag,
> >     non-alphanumeric characters in backreferences will be escaped.

Comment: Didn't work with b flag too.  Can you write the full block of code you meant?

Comment: Hello @Prakash., ok what about this Q&A? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459667/how-to-encode-special-characters-using-mod-rewrite-apache