# How to Redirect an URL with special characters %ef%bb%bf?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, special-characters

I have links on my Wordpress website with %ef%bb%bf at the end of URLs, I changed them directly on database, but know I have to redirect the old ones to the new version.

I tried via .htaccess, but it doesn't work :

```
Redirect 301 /category/old-uri%ef%bb%bf/ https://example.com/category/new-uri
```

I tried different variants too, but nothing works.

Do you have ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: What does happen when you request your old link with this `.htaccess` ? Make sure that any `.htaccess` file installed in the same directory is working.

Comment: Nothing happen. The old page with the old url appears. The redirection doesn't work.
I tried with the part without %ef%bb%bf : 

Redirect 301 /category/ https://mywebsite.com/category/new-uri and this goes right.

Comment: OK, then check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720650/htaccess-url-encoded-string-not-passing-to-page-correctly) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/925925/redirect-to-encoded-url-parameter-using-mod-rewrite-in-htaccess).

Comment: the last characters are HTML entities, when I used the HTML table https://krypted.com/utilities/html-encoding-reference/ i got these characters : ï»¿

Comment: I tried the RewriteRule directive instead Redirect 301, but still the redirection doesn't go well and I get a 404. My code : RewriteRule /category/old-uri%ef%bb%bf/ example.com/category/new-uri [B, R=301]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the B rewrite flag. This flag tells mod_rewrite to escape backreferences as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13722058/3623080) in @Accountant link.

```
Redirect 301 /category/old-uri%ef%bb%bf/ https://example.com/category/new-uri [B]
```

Will escape the special character and lead `https://example.com/category/old-uri%ef%bb%bf/` to The new url `https://example.com/category/new-uri`

Comment: It added the [B at the end of the line, it ]gives me an "Internal Server Error" for the entire website.

Comment: Hi Gael, 

I just used the RewriteRule directive instead Redirect 301. I no longer get the Internal Server Error, but still the redirection doesn't go well and I get a 404.

My code :
RewriteRule /category/old-uri%ef%bb%bf/ https://example.com/category/new-uri [B, R=301]

Comment: do you have other rules in your htaccess that could cause the Internal server error? The code in my answer works without error on my test website.

Comment: That code is encapsulated in a <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

But before that one, yes there is other rules, in other <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> like this one :

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
# Les directives (lignes) entre 'BEGIN WordPress' et 'END WordPress' sont
# généré dynamiquement, et ne doivent uniquement être modifiées via les filtres WordPress.
# Toute modification des directives entre ces marqueurs sera outrepassée.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Comment: There is other rules before that one too, like an <IfModule mod_mime.c> or an <IfModule mod_expires.c>, a <IfModule mod_deflate.c>, a <IfModule mod_headers.c>

Those are generated by Wordpress.

Comment: So try to put the code in my answer at the very top of your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: ça à marché ? :)